# Regular Expression required for condition

Tags: asp.net

I need a regular expression which can match a string with the following requirements:

1. Must be between 6 and 64 characters long
2. Cannot include the following symbols : @, &, ', <, >, !, ", /, #, $, %, +, ?, (, ), *, [ , ] , \ , { , }
3. Cannot contain spaces, tabs, or consecutive underscores, i.e. __
4. Cannot contain elements that imply an email address or URL, such as ".com", ".net", ".org", ".edu" or any variation (e.g. "_com" or "-com")
5. Cannot start with underscore '_', dash '-' or period '.'
6. Cannot contain the words  "honey" or "allied"
7. Cannot contain single letter followed by numbers

Comment: What do you have so far? What didn't work for you?

Comment: about point 2: what about ß, § or other symbols? Maybe you are better of specifying "only a-z, A-Z or 0-9"

Answer (score 1):

This is better done with several regular expressions! And some of your conditions don't even need regexes (in fact, they would be counter productive).

1. use a string length function
2. use a function looking up for that character in your string;
3. match against `_{2,}` and `\s`
4. match against `[._-](?:com|net|....)`
5. use a string function looking for these characters at the first position, or `^[-._]`
6. whole words? What about "calliedaaa"? If whole words, match against `\b(?:honey|allied)\b`, otherwise use a string lookup function
7. match against `\w\d+`